# dynamics CRM 2011 and VS 2012 SDK, cannot deploy to an existing solution (plugin error)

Tags: visual-studio-2012, plugins, dynamics-crm-2011

I have to make changes to an existing solution of CRM 2011.
Therefore I am using VS 2012 and the CRM 2011 SDK.
The VS CRM Package consists of some webresources and 2 plugins.
I haven't made any changes to the plugins but it seems they are responsible for the error.

When I want to deploy the solution via VS 2012 to the existing solution I am getting following error:

> Error registering plugins and/or workflows. An unexpected error
>   occurred. C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\CRM\Microsoft.CrmDeveloperTools.12.targets    176 4

I've enabled tracing on my Server and in the logfile the following is stated:

> > Web Service Plug-in failed in SdkMessageProcessingStepId: {C03B8615-ECD8-DB11-B397-0019B9204DA9}; EntityName:
> >     sdkmessageprocessingstep; Stage: 30; MessageName: Create;
> >     AssemblyName: Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.InternalOperationPlugin,
> >     Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> >     PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35; ClassName:
> >     Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.InternalOperationPlugin; Exception:
> >     Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException:
> >     Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.    at
> >     System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[]
> >     arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)    at
> >     System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
> >     Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)    at
> >     System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
> >     invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
> >     at System.Web.Services.Protocols.LogicalMethodInfo.Invoke(Object
> >     target, Object[] values)    at
> >     Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.InternalOperationPlugin.Execute(IServiceProvider
> >     serviceProvider)    at
> >     Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.V5PluginProxyStep.ExecuteInternal(PipelineExecutionContext
> >     context)    at
> >     Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.VersionedPluginProxyStepBase.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext
> >     context) Inner Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object
> >     reference not set to an instance of an object.    at
> >     Microsoft.Crm.Platform.SolutionAwareComponents.ComponentStateTransitionFactory.CreateStateTransition(FactoryInput
> >     input, ComponentStateTransitionActionFactory actionFactory)    at
> >     Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.BusinessProcessObject.DoCreate(IBusinessEntity
> >     entity, ExecutionContext context)

I've wasted hours with finding the solution to this problem - but without luck.
If I deploy the CRM-Package to a newly created solution it is working.

Can anyone help with this please?

Thanks

---

edit:
I am on rollup 15, but tried it on different rollups as well (11,13,17..)
I've also tried it with different machines (CRM Server and Client machines)

Comment: Do you get the same error if you use the plugin registration tool, and not the VS plugin?

Comment: I can update the plugins using the registration tool without any errormessages.

I've also tried to unregister the plugin with the registration tool and deploy the plugins via VS - same error as before